# PyQt - Function for zooming large Images

Tags: image, pyqt, zooming, scale

I need a function for zooming very large images (5000 x 7000 pixel) in pyqt.

I´ve tried out the functions from gwenview (Image viewer coded in C++ and Qt), but it`s too difficult for me to understand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i had the same trouble before , i had to make a system to draw over picture and save the result. the best approach i found is to : 
**1-** subclass QGraphicView add a pixmap using :  `self.createPixmapItem(QPixmap(self.image),pos) inside the subClass`  
**2-** in the subclass also , re implement the wheel event like so :
 
    `def wheelEvent(self, event):   # code from (rapid GUI programming using python and pyqt ) book.`

```
    factor = 1.41 ** (event.delta() / 240.0)
    self.scale(factor, factor)
```

(copying and pasting the function inside the QgraphicView subclass should work fine for you)

my case was kind of more complicated than your case since i had to make a complete drawing system _ or a comment system _ (Zoom , draw ,erase and undo ..etc ). that's why i had to use the QgraphicsView , im pretty sure that there are some easier ways to do you case but i hope you'll find this usefull .

Comment: in your case , i think adding an label , setting  a pixmap for that label. (like the image viewer) . then use the wheel event above ( with scaling the label instead of (self) .) will be enough

Comment: This way is the first i tried, but it`s to slow for large images. It takes over 5 sec for a zoom-step. Not very efficient :)

Comment: did you try the QGraphicView method ?,i think it will be faster .

Comment: well , me too experiencing this...is there an answer to this question ? it'll be helpful

Comment: @MoayyadYaghi I have same problembut I don't understand what you did . You don't write it clearly .

Answer (score 0):

In my app I have a grid which I hide when the user zooms out beyond a certain point. I acheived this by sending a signal of the zoom level whenever it changes, and catching that in a slot in the scene to enable or diable the grid. You could do the same to switch image files to a lower resolution copy of the image when you're zoomed out beyond a certain point.